# SQL - Select like string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following table:

```
create table #tbl
(
    PartNumber varchar(20)
)

insert into #tbl values ('003A-I00-1')
insert into #tbl values ('003A-INT-1')
insert into #tbl values ('003A-I1')
insert into #tbl values ('003A-I2')
insert into #tbl values ('003A-I3')
```

I need to select the **highest PartNumber** where PartNumber is equal to **003A-I** followed only by **a number (or numbers)**. In other words, I need **003A-I3**.

What I've tried:

```
select top 1 partnumber
from #tbl
where partnumber like '003A-I%' + '%[0-9]'
order by partnumber desc
```

But it doesn't work. It returns **003A-INT-1**. I need **003A-I3**.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select top 1 partnumber
from tbl
where partnumber like '003A-I[0-9]%'
order by partnumber desc
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54cad/2)

Update (in response to @Nicarus's comment:

```
SELECT top 1 partnumber
FROM tbl
WHERE partnumber LIKE '003A-I[0-9]%'
ORDER BY convert(varbinary(200), partnumber) DESC
```

Comment: If you have a different collation set, you could get different results because you are ordering by text

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the numeric values, you can use the `ISNUMERIC()` function of the SQL
The code will be:

```
select * from #tbl
where isnumeric(replace(partnumber, '003A-I', '')) = 1
order by partnumber desc
```

***REVISE:***

`ISNUMERIC()` function returns Boolean value either true or false (1 or 0).
`REPLACE()` function replaces a certain pattern in an expression or string

For more information:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

***UPDATE (2):***
You can use the following if you don't want to match a specific word, but as long as you know the text size which would be replaced

```
select top 1 * from #tbl
where isnumeric(substring(partnumber, 7, LEN(partnumber))) = 1
order by partnumber desc
```

The link on the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/54cad/8/0)

Comment: Will match `103A-I` (for example).

Comment: If you're talking about the `REPLACE()` function, yes it can easily math that or other text. Or a generic solution if you know the size of the text before the Number you can use the `SUBSTRING()` function. For an example `SUBSTRING(partnumber, 0, 5)` and use it inside the `ISNUMERIC()` function

Comment: alos returns all matches...not just Max

Comment: @MitchWheat You can easily select top 1, since you are order by partnumber desc. If using the `SUBSTRING()` function, the full code will be as pasted in my answer